# using ngClass is not working 100% of the time even though using class.name does

Tags: angular

I am using the below code block div in iteration and the output is not 100% the same....

```
<div
  class="header-wrapper {{ componentSize }} {{ currentTheme }}"
  [ngClass]="{
    'header-wrapper-selected': isSelected,
    'header-wrapper-active-alarm': activeAlarm,
    'header-wrapper-active-alarm-selected': activeAlarm && isSelected,
    disconnected: isDisconnected
  }"
  [class.headerWrapperActiveAlarm]="activeAlarm"
>
```

I am trying to understand Why in the following code... the ngClass does not always work 100% of the time, it does sometimes but not all the time? specifically when the activeAlarm returns true ut should show the header-wrapper-active-alarm respectively but when it returns true the header-wrapper-active-alarm does not always show up in the html class.

however the headerWrapperActiveAlarm does every time (so it is a band aid fix, but I am wondering if anyone could explain why the ngClass does not always work when the [class. does)

even

[class.header-wrapper-active-alarm]="activeAlarm"

does not work....

the css is this (not really relevant but added for completeness)

```
.headerWrapperActiveAlarm,
.header-wrapper-active-alarm {
  border: 1px solid var(--warn-color) !important;
  border-style: dotted;
  background-color: #ed2b2e17;
}
```

so the above code block for the first few iterations will show this..

```
<div class="headerWrapperActiveAlarm header-wrapper tall titan-theme header-wrapper-active-alarm" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">...</div>
```

but then it will start outputing this...

```
<div class="headerWrapperActiveAlarm header-wrapper tall titan-theme" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">...</div>
```

notice that the  header-wrapper-active-alarm class is missing even though the ngClass of activeAlarm Boolean is true...

Any thoughts as to why that is would be greatly appreciated... (for now I will use the Band-Aid just seems illogical...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue is likely with the code that sets the value of `activeAlarm`, so add that code to your question as well if you can.

Comment: The code that sets activeAlarm doesnt seem to make any difference I set it to true always and it still happens.

this.activeAlarm = true;

Comment: Can you recreate the issue in a stackblitz?

Comment: You has a typo error, the "disconected" should be `'disconected'` -between quotes-. BTW use a "default value to your css var": `border: 1px dotted var(--warn-color,red) !important;` to avoid not show if not defined the variable.

Comment: Good idea, i will give it a try and share here if I can recreate it...

Comment: Ok, so stackblitz has helped me realize that the issue is with {{ currentTheme }} its called via a subscribe and seems to change the class for some reason (even though the subscribe that updates currentTheme I can console log the activeAlarm is still true makes no sense... but I cant seem to recreate the error in stackblitz everything seems to be called properly

Comment: This is the function that stops it from working if I comment it out then everything works as expected
private getEqpProfile() {
    this.channelsService.getEqpProfile(this.pumpType, this.pumpID).subscribe(
      (response) => {
ACIThemes.BJCONVENTIONAL;
        this.currentTheme = ACIThemes.BJTITAN;
      },
      (error: Error) => {
        console.error(error ? (error.message ? error.message : error) : 'Error happened but no Error message returned');
      }
    );
  }

Comment: The solution, if anyone needs in the future was to change the currentTheme as a behavior subject and now everything works because it was for some reason it was removing the class on a change another option would have been to use       this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, if anyone needs in the future was to change the currentTheme variable to a behavior subject and now everything works because it was for some reason it was removing the class on a change another option would have been to use this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();